# hadoop 2.6.2 , mkdir : Couldn't create proxy provider null

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, admin, bigdata

i am not able to create new file or directory nor able to list the existing files or directory

i am using below command to do the operation ,could you please suggest

```
 hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
8546 ResourceManager
9181 Jps
1503 NameNode
8674 NodeManager
4398 DataNode
hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -ls /
ls: Couldn't create proxy provider null
hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /books
mkdir: Couldn't create proxy provider null
hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

below is my `hdfs-site.xml` ,which i am using it .

```
<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>mycluster</value>
    </property>

<property>
<name>dfs.replicaion</name>
<value>2</value>
<description>to specifiy replication</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/h3iHA/name</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/h3iHA/data2</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name>
<value>nn1,nn2</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
<value>c:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
<value>a:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
<value>c:50070</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
<value>a:50070</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
<value>file:///mnt/filer</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.configuredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
<value>sshfence</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
<value>/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
<value>sshfence
       shell(/bin/true)
</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core file ,which is same for both nodes

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is this HA cluster?

Comment: Yes, this is HA cluster.

Comment: Can you post your `hdfs-site.xml`

Comment: i have shared my hdfs configuration file ,could you please review and advise,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java class name set for the property `dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster` is incorrect. It is **`ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider`** and not **`configuredFailoverProxyProvider`**.

Edit the value of this property in `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
</property>
```

Comment: thank you franklinksijo .i have a doubt (1) i need to format to my namenode again? (2) or just i need to start my namenode since this command hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -ls / still throwing the errors  ls: Call From a/192.168.0.105 to a:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: No, format isn't required. The proxy error is fixed. This is different, Is `a` your current active namenode? What do you have set for `fs.defaultFS`?

Comment: node c is active and node a is standby . and my core file is same for both nodes ,updated now ,you may review 

hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -ls /
hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -lsr /
lsr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'ls -R' instead.
hduser@c:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
1703 ResourceManager
1832 NodeManager
2729 Jps
1535 NameNode
2570 DataNode
hduser@a:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fs -ls /
hduser@a:/usr/local/hadoop$ ls /

Comment: @Maverick I do not see an error in the comment you have posted. Can you clarify.

Comment: could you also please advise : what could be the possible reason if we are not able to start the namenode on partner node after doing bootstrapStandby -force command in HA hadoop cluster : error message >>2017-04-21 03:38:28,222 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer: Unable to trigger a roll of the active NN
java.net.ConnectException: Call From c/192.168.0.104 to a:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;